# Replacing wildcard text using jquery

Tags: jquery, text, replace, wildcard

I have a database that contains company information (address, telephone etc)

On some of the telephone numbers it will have an international code: +44 (0) 123 12345

where the (0) will be different numbers depending on country.

I need to strip the (0)

I have the following code:

```
var el = $('#contactdetails');
el.html(el.html().replace("(0)", "-"));
```

which works on (0) - but how do I do this for wildcards

Answer (score 5):

Use a regular expression.

```
var el = $('#contactdetails');
el.html(el.html().replace(/\([0-9]\)/, "-"));
```

If there is more than a singe digit, then use the `*` for any number of occurrences of the previous expression.

```
el.html(el.html().replace(/\([0-9]*\)/, "-"));
```

[Live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/CfZjF/)

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply works great apart from some of the numbers will be 3 characters (758) - i tryed changing [0-9] to [0-999] but no luck - any ideas?