# Removing the day from a date string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I am trying to remove the "day" from every possible date occurrence on a page.

This is to make jQuery turn every date in the format of "08/22/2012" into "08/2012"

I was able to do this with this code: [Replacing wildcard text using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606853/replacing-wildcard-text-using-jquery)

See my fiddle for more information: http://jsfiddle.net/CfZjF/223/

But it just isn't working within this table layout, regardless of what I have tried.

Another problem will be to specify the day specifically (maybe with wildcards?)-- that is the 2 numbers between the forward-slashes: /xx/, but please see the fiddle for more info.

Any ideas on how I can pull this off?

Comment: are *all* the dates currently in the form xx/xx/xxxx?

Comment: Do you want to modify all the dates or just the ones in the row with class even?

Comment: Phillip: Yes.
j08691: All of the dates. I'll be using this to review webform results.

Comment: Wow, that's a high revision number! You should create a new fiddle (or `fork` it) when testing a new thing. And you can `run` them without updating :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
str.replace(/\/\d+\//g, "/");
```

Or be more specific by replacing `/(\d{2})\/\d{2}\/(\d{4})/g` with `"$1/$2"` or something…

([Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CfZjF/224/))

Comment: Thank you again for this, sir. It will be of benefit to the Drupal community: http://drupal.org/node/1762320

Answer (score 1):

I think you should individually traverse the table cells instead of trying to globally muck with the entire rows HTML.

This assumes that your data is formatted as in your jsFiddle.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GKrCS/

```
$('tr').each(function(){
       $('td',this).not(':first').text(
           function(){
               return $(this).text().replace(/\/[0-9]+\//,'/');
           });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all your dates are in the form xx/xx/xxxx, using a simple split() would always split it into an array with these values:

```
xx,xx,xxxx
```

So, something like this:

```
var totalDate = $("whateverYourDateSelectorMightBe");
var daysInMiddle = totalDate.val().ToString().split(",")[1];
```

so then you could do:

```
totalDate.val(totalDate.val().ToString().replace(daysInMiddle + "/",""));
```

Note that there are much cleaner ways to do this. I just did it this way because I think it better explains what I was trying to do.