# Replace Numbers in Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I am trying to replace / remove multiple Charactes out of a String. From Sharepoint i take multiple Values as far as i can see i cannot remove those ID Informations while i am get the Values out of a list with sharepointPlus Script. So i try to do it later with jquery and replace.
What i get from the List is the following:

- 4;#Galaxy S6;#
- 5;#Galaxy S6 edge;#
- 15;#Galaxy S6 edge+;#
- 1;#iPhone 6;#13;#iPhone 6 Plus;#2;#iPhone 6s;#14;#iPhone 6s Plus

Structure to be removed: ;#number and ;# after the Device Name.

As i can see the structure is different, the Main Entries has ID;#Name;#
the Last One just ID;#Name

The part of the script that i currently use is:

```
$("td.affectedDevices:contains(';#')").each(function() {
    $(this).html(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace('0', '')
                   .replace('1', '')
                   .replace('2', '')
                   .replace('3', '')
                   .replace('4', '')
                   .replace('5', '')
                   .replace('6', '')
                   .replace('7', '')
                   .replace('8', '')
                   .replace('9', '')
                   .replace(';#', '');
    });
});
```

I am using this Code on another Place where i take just one Entry out of the Table, then it works.

The Problem is, the JS Above takes the First "Number;#" entry of each String... AND the Number of the Device as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: ActualState]

Should be Galaxy S6 `<br />` Galaxy S6 edge and so on...

i am found already some similar questions & answers here but the solutions don't worked at all...

[Replacing Wildcard Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606853/replacing-wildcard-text-using-jquery)
the solution looks good but

```
$("td.affectedDevices:contains(';#')").each(function() {
    $(this).html(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace(/\([0-9]\);#/, '');
    });
});
```

Doesn't have any effect...
Anyone can help me to solve this? Or a better idea to do the whole thing?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcxaozt2/1/)

Thanks for your help
Kind regards

Comment: could you please add up a fiddle or your HTML here to be clear?

Comment: can you try below :     $("td.affectedDevices:contains(';#')").each(function(index, text) {
        var text = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(text.replace(/\([0-9]\);#/, '');
       });

Comment: Is there no way to improve the data in your database? This is a clear case of GIGO

Comment: Why are you escaping your regex parenthesises making them literal characters? `text.replace(/\([0-9]\);#/, '')` means "a start parenthesis followed by a digit between 0 and 9 followed by an end parenthesis followed by a semicolon followed by a shebang". Use `/[0-9]?;#/g` instead meaning "an optional digit between 0 and 9 followed by a semicolon followed by a shebang - replace ALL occurences (`/g`)". If there may be more than 1 digit, use `*` meaning "0 to infinite matches"; `/[0-9]*;#/g`

Comment: @Dreamweaver : Syntax error i changed your ideea to $(document).ready(function(){
                 $("td.affectedDevices:contains(';#')").each(function(index, text) { var text = $(this).html(); $(this).html(text.replace(/([0-9]);#/, '')); });
            }); 
But no change

Comment: can i know, what output do you expect on `1;#iPhone 6;#13;#iPhone 6 Plus;#2;#iPhone 6s;#14;#iPhone 6s Plus`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo i don't understand this fully so i copy / pasted just something ;-)  - i tried your solution with:

$(document).ready(function(){
                 $("td.1affectedDevices:contains(';#')").each(function() {
                                $(this).html(function(index, text) {
                                return text.replace(/[0-9]?;#/g, '');
                                });
                            });
            });

But no effect

Comment: @ameenulla0007 finaly all in one tablecell and seperated by breakes or comma - the tablecell around already exists (td.affectedDevices) on the screenshot above you can see the final result... and how it arleady works

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan GIGO... ;-) - the Problem is that the source is a Sharepoint Table, data will be taken via SharepointPlus 3.12 Script - if someone knows how to stripe the ID Informations out directly via SharepointPlus... you are welcome :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("td").each(function() {
    $(this).html(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace(/[0-9]?;#/g, '').replace(/^[0-9]/g, '');
    });
});
```

Hope this would help you.

Here is the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1u6brd3m/

Comment: got it THX

Final Solution was:

$("td").each(function() {
                    $(this).html(function(index, text) {
                        return text.replace(/;#?[0-9]*?;#/g, '<br />').replace(/[0-9]*?;#/g, '');
                    });
                });

Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
$("td.affectedDevices:contains(';#')").each(function() {
    var string = $(this).html(),
    split = string.split('#'),
    newContent = '',
    re = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

    $.each(split, function( key, value ) {
        if(/^[a-zA-Z]/.test(value)) newContent = newContent + value.replace(';', '') + '<br />';
    });
    $(this).html(newContent);
});
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vgkyoywq/

Good luck!